# How to speed up only a part of an animation?

Tags: animation

I'm doing my first animation right now, so I'm not the best at such things :D yet. I'd like to know if it's possible to speed up only a selected part of my animation. I use a path in my animation that my character follows. Here is my blender file: [image] maybe you can tell what i did wrong or i need to do, to fix my problem, when you take a look at it.

Comment: Is your animation just an object following a path or is it a character walking along a path (much more complicated)?

Comment: It is an Character with an Armature, that is falling down a cliff, i want him to fall faster then he walks before. So it makes more sense. With Ctrl+P i combined the armature with the path, i clicked on "Follow Path".

Comment: Research Time Remapping. You can keyframe it too, to easily and non-destructively slow down a whole scene

Answer (score 1):

I make an edit as it looks like you don't need to use a *Follow Path* constraint and a simple parentage is enough.

- So, once you parented the object (in your case, the penguin's armature) to your curve, you will just play with the *Evaluation Time* value of your object, in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path Animation*..
- Go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path Animation*.
- Select the *Frames* rate you want, 100 is good.
- In the *Timeline* (or *Dopesheet*) window, point the cursor where you want the animation to begin, for example frame 1.
- For this frame 1, choose the object position along the curve with the *Evaluation Time* value. Once it's good for you, put your mouse over the *Evaluation Time* value and press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert a keyframe.
- Again, in the *Timeline* (or *Dopesheet*) window, point the cursor where you want the animation to change speed, for example frame 50.
- For this frame 50, choose the object position along the curve with the *Evaluation Time* value. Once it's good for you, insert a keyframe with <kbd>i.</kbd>
- Etc, etc, you can make your penguin move forward, backward, etc, at the speed you want.
- You can change the transitions in the Graph Editor with T > *Interpolations*.

[image]

old answer, with the *Follow Path* constraint:

The speed has been automatically generated when you gave your object a *Follow Path* constraint. If you want to vary the speed of the object along the path, you need to:

- Select the path, open the *Graph Editor*, on the left panel, unfold the *BezierCurve* menu and click on *Evaluation Time*.
- On the right panel of the *Graph Editor*, *Modifiers* tab, you'll now see the *Generator* box that has been generated by the constraint. Delete it. Now your object don't move any more, but you'll be able to determine its speed manually.
- Keep the path selected and go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path Animation*. If you change the *Evaluation Time* value you can see that the object moves along the curve.
- Select the *Frames* rate you want, 100 is good.
- In the *Timeline* (or *Dopesheet*) window, point the cursor where you want the animation to begin, for example frame 1.
- For this frame 1, choose the object position along the curve with the *Evaluation Time* value. Once it's good for you, insert a keyframe with i.
- Again, in the *Timeline* (or *Dopesheet*) window, point the cursor where you want the animation to change speed, for example frame 50.
- For this frame 50, choose the object position along the curve with the *Evaluation Time* value. Once it's good for you, insert a keyframe with i.
- Etc.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85631/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-how-to-speed-up-only-a-part-of-an-animation).